# Некорректно отображаются некоторые примеры кода на MSDN

Tags: c#, .net

На MSDN встречаются примеры кода, где нарушено форматирование:

Например, многострочный код может быть написан в одну строку=> если в начале кода стоит комментарий, то весь код отображается как комментарий...

Приходится каждый такой пример копировать в notepad++ и руками корректировать.

Подскажите, можно ли это как-то исправить?

Пробовал стандартный IE открывать и язык переключать, но не помогло...

**UPD**

Пример:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private Program() { //An aggregate catalog that combines multiple catalogs var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(); //Adds all the parts found in the same assembly as the Program class catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly)); //Create the CompositionContainer with the parts in the catalog _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog); //Fill the imports of this object try { this._container.ComposeParts(this); } catch (CompositionException compositionException) { Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString()); } }
```

Comment: Хоть ссылки бы добавили на такое дело, а то не сталкивался я например.

Comment: странно, у меня только на русском воспроизводится, на английской странице все ок: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Судя по тому, что на оригинальной английской странице с форматированием все нормально, нужно сказать спасибо автоматическому переводчику, который видимо пытается перевести еще и код, а попутно ломает разметку.

Comment: Ага, переводчика собсна и подозревал, почему и спрашивал. Это на мой взгляд нормально, там и текст иногда невнятный, что уж от кода то ждать.

Comment: Я могу такую ссылку привести: [LockBits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5ey6h79d(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3). В примере кода присутствуют символы `���`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У этого есть, по крайней мере, две причины. Первая - код сам по себе опубликован в кривом виде. С этим ничего не поделать.

Вторая причина - наглядный пример того, почему не надо парсить код регулярками. На всех сайтах подсветка синтаксиса сделана простыми регулярками (в браузере иначе не сделать). Итог:

c#:

Так не работает:

```
string quote = @"\"";
int x = 0;
```

А так работает (нужно явно указать язык `<!-- language: lang-c# -->`):

```c#
string quote = @"\"";
int x = 0;
```

xml:

```xml
<root atr="value">
    <узел атр="знач"/>
</root>
```

Как видим, даже здесь, на stackoverflow, подсветка нарушается в ряде случаев.

---

Пофантазирую. Что с этим можно сделать? Дело осложняется тем, что на форумах обычно публикуют кусочки кода, которые не полны по своей сути. То есть парсер должен понимать не только синтаксис, но и семантику языка, уметь делать восстановление и продолжать разбор после встреченной ошибки. Это уже умеет Roslyn (компилятор c#).

Следовательно, подсветка синтаксиса и форматирование должны осуществляться путём разбора кода полноценным парсером. Для этого нужен плагин(ы) к браузеру, заточенный под конкретный язык. Или, как вариант, парсинг осуществляется на сервере, а в браузер отдаётся готовая разметка.

Comment: "С этим ничего не поделать." интересно, а существует ли плагины для браузера, который форматируют код?

Comment: @user2455111 - наверняка, да. Однако, если что и есть, то там примитивный разбор опять-таки регулярками. С использованием парсера/компилятора - не слышал о таких. Есть шанс стать первопроходцем ;)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я тебе сломал пример с c# возможно его стоит удалить :)

Comment: @Grundy - Шайтан! Однако, если просто стоит тег `c#` в вопросе, то подсветка осуществляется как в первоначальном варианте.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да тут не всегда понятно как именно он что выбирает. Кстати попробовал то же самое с xml, но не прокатило, судя по всему из-за наличия не английских символов

Comment: @Grundy - хотел на мете вопрос задать, а там не воспроизводится эффект: в обоих случаях подсветка корректная.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, про xml?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov правильное имя языка для C# - `lang-cs`, а не `lang-c#`. c `lang-c#` срабатывает подсветка по умолчанию - `lang-default`. Вот полный список доступных языков: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я обновил ответ на мете - http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4254/177221. У вас в примере невалидный код на C#, в нем `int x = 0;` является частью строки. и он подсвечивается корректно. а вот указание `lang-c#` приводит к неккоректной подсветке :)